# Angular 2 Multiple Category Checkbox Filter With Reactive Form

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, filter, categories

I'm trying to do a more complex (for me) filter with 2 different categories (hopefully more), frameBrand & frameColor. I want to filter down to a specific brand, then use those results to filter colors until I have a more specific/narrow search. I'm struggling with filtering 2 categories

With my example JSON below, I'd like to click a brand checkbox to get "anne klein" frames then click a color checkbox "brown" to view the "anne klein - brown" frame. 2 checkboxes each from different "categories". Ideally, I'd be able to expand this to use other categories, like checkboxes for price. I've used StackOverflow to get where I'm at with .filter but haven't seen much with multiple categories and checkboxes using Angular.

```
{
  "frames": [
    {
      "frameBrand": "altair",
      "frameColor": "Black",
      "frameId": 1,
      "frameName": "A5052",
      "releaseDate": "05-01-2021",
      "framePrice": 25,
      "frameDescription": "this is an altair frame.",
      "imageUrl": "/assets/images/frames/ALO/A5052/A5052_001_LG_01.jpg",
      "categories": [1]
    },
    {
      "frameBrand": "anne klein",
      "frameColor": "Ruby",
      "frameId": 2,
      "frameName": "AK5091",
      "releaseDate": "05-01-2021",
      "framePrice": 45,
      "frameDescription": "this is an anne klein frame.",
      "imageUrl": "/assets/images/frames/AKO/AK5091/AK5091_610_LG_01.jpg",
      "categories": [2]
    },
    {
      "frameBrand": "anne klein",
      "frameColor": "Brown",
      "frameId": 3,
      "frameName": "AK5090",
      "releaseDate": "05-01-2021",
      "framePrice": 45,
      "frameDescription": "this is an anne klein frame.",
      "imageUrl": "/assets/images/frames/AKO/AK5090/AK5090_200_LG_01.jpg",
      "categories": [2]
    },
    {
      "frameBrand": "bebe",
      "frameColor": "Silver",
      "frameId": 4,
      "frameName": "BB5192",
      "releaseDate": "05-01-2021",
      "framePrice": 40,
      "frameDescription": "this is an bebe frame.",
      "imageUrl": "/assets/images/frames/BBO/BB5192/BB5192_001_LG_01.jpg",
      "categories": [3]
    }
  ]
}
```

In my TS file I have 3 functions, filterFramesByBrand, filterFramesByColor and filterResults. I take the checked checkboxes from brands and colors and push them to different array's in my formGroup when (change)="filterFramesByBrand($event)" occurs. Then I run the filterResults function where I'm trying to make the magic happen. I've gotten the brands to filter as expected but mixing the 2 categories (brands and colors) has me stumped. I've commented out the color section of my filterResults function because it's not working like the brands section for some reason.

```
checkboxForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.checkboxForm = this.fb.group({
    brandCheckArray: this.fb.array([]),
    colorCheckArray: this.fb.array([])
  });
}


filteredFrames: IFrames[] = [...this.frames];

  filterFramesByBrand(category) {
    const brandCheckArray: FormArray = this.checkboxForm.get(
      "brandCheckArray"
    ) as FormArray;

    if (category.target.checked) {
      brandCheckArray.push(new FormControl(category.target.value));
    } else {
      let i: number = 0;
      brandCheckArray.controls.forEach((item: FormControl) => {
        if (item.value == category.target.value) {
          brandCheckArray.removeAt(i);
          return;
        }
        i++;
      });
    }
    this.filterResults();
  }

  filterFramesByColor(category) {
    const colorCheckArray: FormArray = this.checkboxForm.get(
      "colorCheckArray"
    ) as FormArray;

    if (category.target.checked) {
      colorCheckArray.push(new FormControl(category.target.value));
    } else {
      let i: number = 0;
      colorCheckArray.controls.forEach((item: FormControl) => {
        if (item.value == category.target.value) {
          colorCheckArray.removeAt(i);
          return;
        }
        i++;
      });
    }
    this.filterResults();
  }

  filterResults() {
    this.filteredFrames = this.frames.filter(el => {
      let frameBrandEl = el.frameBrand
        .split(" ")
        .join("")
        .toLowerCase();
      // let frameColorsEl = el.frameColor
      //   .split(" ")
      //   .join("")
      //   .toLowerCase();

      let brandsChecked = this.checkboxForm.get("brandCheckArray").value;
      // let colorsChecked = this.checkboxForm.get("colorCheckArray").value;

      var fixCheckedBrands = brandsChecked.map(v =>
        v
          .split(" ")
          .join("")
          .toLowerCase()
      );
      // var fixCheckedColors = colorsChecked.map(v =>
      //   v
      //     .split(" ")
      //     .join("")
      //     .toLowerCase()
      // );

      console.log(frameBrandEl);
      // console.log(frameColorsEl);

      console.log(fixCheckedBrands);
      // console.log(fixCheckedColors);

      return frameBrandEl.includes(fixCheckedBrands);
      // return frameColorsEl.includes(fixCheckedColors);
    });

    // if there are no checked checkboxes - show all
    if (this.checkboxForm.value.brandCheckArray.length === 0) {
      this.filteredFrames = this.frames;
    }
  }
```

Finally: here is a link to my StackBlitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-product-filters?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproduct-filter.ts I think with a bit of guidance on the .filter function I could figure this out. Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simplify you logic.
Instead of doing this with `FormGroup` of `FormArrays` (unless that is not requirement) the best here would be to create `FilterComponent` which accepts as input exemplary object
`type CheckboxFilter = { name: string, isChecked: boolean }`. Probably you could add `id` if neccessary.
Having that created add `Output` to your `FilterComponent`.
Now you add to handlers for that `BrandChanged` and `ColorChanged`. Based on that you are able to store selected filters and apply them on your frames.

That even allows you to make it more reacive way.
You could decalre `BehaviourSubject<string[]>` for both `Brand` and `Color` and once there is event you could manipulate subject.
Later just `combainLatest` of your frames that came from JSON file or API and apply do it like this:

```
combineLatest([frames$, brands$, colors$]).pipe(filter([frames, brands, colors]) => ...)
```

Here is working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-product-filters-eiqxqk?file=src/app/product-filter.ts)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will look this over and learn from it! Genuinely curious though, why use a "type" instead of an "interface"?

Comment: There is not much of a difference between `type` and `interface`. I think the most annoying thing that can happen with interfaces is `merge` while `type` would throw exception if you have two same types. Second is that I've c# background and it feels more intuitive for me to say `Foo type` :)

Comment: I forgot to mention that, there is an issue with `ids` of checkboxes. While you use component you cannot add `id` `attribute` in the way it was done.

Comment: ah, okay. I might change it to an interface and add them all to a directory so they are together and it cleans up the projects. I noticed the ID issue too. I know how to fix that issue though. Thanks again for your help. I'm learning a lot from your code. Will have to look up quite a bit of docs though, like combineLatest RxJs.

Comment: 1 more question - should a lot of this code be in services? Then call the data from there? Would that be better?

Comment: That really depends. If you are going to have more filters, I'd go with NgRx. Because most likely you are going to load data from some API instead of filtering in-memory collection on client side.
So that would allow you to create some kind of `filters-component` that has `brand-filter`, `color-filter`, `foo-filter`. Each filter would be setting data in store and you would have effect for filter change that would be reloading data from API.

If you still want to use in-memory collection, that is still fine to implement store.
However if you finish on two filters it's ok to go with service